# Box2D bodies moving for no reason?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection

I am using Box2D with Cocos2D in my app. So pretty much in my app I make the bodies follow my CCSprites even though people recommend against it. Also I only use Box2D for collision detection so I just attach a body to my sprites and use a b2ContactListener and ***nothing*** else. Anyway this setup works for the most part except this little issue.

So my bodies follow my sprites like this in the game loop:

```
for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
                b2Vec2 b2Position = b2Vec2(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
                float32 b2Angle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(sprite.rotation);
                b->SetTransform(b2Position, b2Angle);
        }
    }
```

Also I create my b2World like this (if it makes any difference):

```
world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
world->SetAllowSleeping(NO);
_contactListener = new MyContactListener();
world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);
```

This issue is, whenever my CCSprites collide (technically my b2Bodys are colliding too), the b2Body on each CCSprite seems to move a bit as if a tiny force just hit it so they have a "recoil" if that makes sense. They move farther away from each other when the hit occurs even though no forces are involved.

Another example is when one of my bodies sits on top of another body, the body that is being stood on seems to tilt a bit when I am on the edge of it which is odd because I don't tilt my sprites.

Lastly, my bodies seem to be a bit behind on where the sprite is at that exact moment and I am not sure if that is also related to this issue but anyway *is there any reason why this would be happening? Is there any way to make it so the bodies are not affected by forces and are solely used for collisions?*

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it goes along the lines of: If two bodies hit and they start moving away from each other, the two bodies must have hit each other with a force. The force on each of them set them in motion, and a body in motion stays in motion unless acted upon. If they are in motion they will not stop because nothing else is acting on them. I think there is likely a force involved.

Comment: Somewhat, when the bodies hit each other, the bodies move differently in an odd direction but soon snap back to the position they used to be in when it reality they shouldn't be moving in that odd direction overall. They should just be following the sprite they are attached to. I must also add nowhere in my project do I apply any forces or any other Box2D related code except for the b2ContactListener.

Comment: Now I am not sure if this is an issue or not, although I do see this behavior when debugging my b2World it may not be the reason the following happens. Now in my game, my bodies are a bit small and they do move fast and sometimes when they should have a collision it misses for an unknown reason although all code is correct it could be because of this or for another reason which I am unsure of. Any tips/ideas/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way but if someone wants to confirm this: Have you tried setting both of the objects to static when the collision happens? `objectA->setType(b2_staticBody)`

Comment: Or better yet set their velocity to zero for both of them when they collide?

Comment: What will setting it to a staticBody achieve, I would just like to know so I know if it should work before changing a lot of code. Also the bodies have no velocity since I don't set it to have any force or anything so that is not the issue.

Comment: Well, I would actually consider probably just setting the velocities to zero, but 2 static bodies would stop moving...

Comment: Sorry if my last post sounded hostile, it was not supposed to be :). Anyway, since static bodies will not move I can't use that because the bodies need to keep moving along with the sprites they are attached to. Also I am not sure what velocities you are speaking of, technically I do set the velocity to 0 since gravity is the only velocity that makes the sprites collide. Also the bodies don't have any velocity so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Static bodies does not seem like the route to go (kentoh has the best solution I would go with that)... But, if an object is moving it has a velocity. Velocity is the change of distance over time (a.k.a. movement). Having gravity = 0,0 just says gravity will not apply a force on the objects. Forces give acceleration, and acceleration causes changes in velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the bodies are triggering a collision response upon collision, which causes them to momentarily move apart a little, before snapping back into position when you force their b2transforms to sync with the sprite's positions/angles in the next game tick.

Since you are using Box2D purely for collision detection, did you set the *isSensor* property of your fixture definition to true?

```
b2FixtureDef shapeDef;
shapeDef.isSensor = true;
```

By specially marking the fixture as a sensor, it will never physically collide with anything, but you will still be notified when an overlap of bodies occur, via the contact listener.

Comment: Currently I do not set isSensor to true anywhere so it is false ATM. But when I do set it to true, my b2ContactListener will work exactly the same right? There shouldn't be any differences that will be noticeable right?

Comment: Oh, I just re-read your answer and it makes sense now. I will try it and will let you know how it goes! :P

Comment: it should work the same. you should be able to grab the contact and inspect the corresponding fixture-pair.

Comment: Making all the fixtures sensors will be enough to tell if two things are touching. However because there is no collision reaction required the engine does not calculate any of the usual contact points or normals, etc. so the contact will *only* be useful for finding which fixtures touched and nothing more. (Most likely this is fine for Brad's case, I am just anticipating the next possible question :)

Comment: Nope I do need the worldManifold for the collision so it is causing my collision ifs not to fire since I check for that too for more accurate collisions.

Comment: I need the manifold because I am trying to achieve a one sided platform so I only want collisions from the top of the platform body to register so unless there is a way to do that while using isSensor, I am not sure how i would work.